# TypeScript type definitions imported in multiple files break app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, enums

I have a problem with using type definitions file in other files.

I have the following folder structure:

```
|_ foo
| |_ service.ts
| |_ schema.ts
| |_ index.ts 
|
|_ types.d.ts
|_ index.ts
```

Here is my `types.d.ts`:

```
export enum EBar {
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b'
}

export interface IBaz {
  id: number,
  title: string
}

export interface IData {
  bar: EBar;
  baz: IBaz[];
}
```

Inside `service.ts` I'm using types:

```
import { EBar, IBaz, IData } from '../types';

// ...functions and methods that utilize these types...
```

Also inside `schema.ts` I'm deriving from types:

```
import Joi from '@hapi/joi';

import { EBar } from '../types';

const BAR_A = EBar.a;
const BAR_B = EBar.b;

export default const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  bar: Joi.string().valid(BAR_A, BAR_B),
  baz: Joi.array().items()
});
```

Both schema and service are imported in `foo/index.ts` file:

```
import { methodA, methodB, methodC } from './service';
import schema from './schema';

// ...use methods and schema
```

However I'm always getting this error when running the app:

```
[Node] Provided module can't be loaded.
[Node] Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
[Node] Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '../types'
```

But when I remove usage of `EBar` inside `scheme.ts` error disappears.

Have anybody experienced something similar?

Repo with reproducible demo - https://github.com/voronianski/ts-types-imports-issue

Comment: It looks like you are having a circular dependencies issue.

Comment: I've also thought about this and used https://github.com/pahen/madge to analyze the code for circular dependencies and got `✔ No circular dependency found!`

Comment: but even if it's circular, it's tricky then, how I would organize code the way I could reuse types in several files?!

Comment: Seems weird then. Are you using tsc directly or something like webpack or parcel ?

Comment: @ClémentBerthou I created github repo with the issue - https://github.com/voronianski/ts-types-imports-issue